# How do I minimize this function $f(x,y,z)$ using lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y,z) = ln(x^2+1)+ln(y^2+1)+ln(z^2+1)$$

subject to $x^2+y^2+z^2=12$

There is both a `max` and `min`. I found the max to be $3\ln(5)$ by setting $x=y=z$ after getting `del`, but I can t find another method to get the min. it s supposed to be $(0,0,-\sqrt{12})$.

Comment: Use `\ln` etc. to get the right font for functions and operators.

Comment: Your attempt doesn't mention Lagrange multipliers. Do you know how to use them? If so, what was the problem when you tried?

Comment: As $\ln$ is an increasing function, your problem is the same as minimizing $(x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)$. Expanding this expression and using the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=12$ will yield a simpler problem.

Comment: I think $-\sqrt{12}$ should be $\pm\sqrt{12}$?

Answer (score 4):

When you set the equation $\frac{2x}{x^2+1}=2\lambda{x}$, you cancel out 2x in to get $\frac{1}{x^2+1}=\lambda$, but you missed a case that x=0.